# How to split image of a hand-written sentence into the words (get coords of beginning and ending of each word)

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, ocr

I'm doing a text recognition script (HCR) and it works fine if I'm giving him just 1 word. But my task is to give him a full text and I'm stuck here...
The text can be vertical and horizontal at the same time.

I'm using Python, OpenCV - morphological convs
But I'm not quite sure that it's working quite good

Here is the example of text:

[image]

Here is my code part:

```
img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 5)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
kernel = np.ones((4, 4))
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)
```

And the result:

[image]

According to the text I don't know how to pull words cords from this...

I have an idea to make yolo detect text word, but I'm not sure in it success and speed.

At this moment I'm thinking maybe to pull text lines from whole text but even here I'm not sure.
Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be using YOLO to detect words, then drop the manipulations you're doing.  No need to do do thresholding, blur, dilate, erode, etc.  Work with the images as-is to get the best results.

And yes, Darknet/YOLO can definitely be used with text.  It is a sequence of pixels -- just numbers! -- and there is no pre-conceived notion of objects that can be physically touched or manipulated.  I use Darknet/YOLO with text extensively, and have posted a few how-to videos on YouTube showing some of the things that can be done.  For example:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxhbXccHEpA

If you train your Darknet/YOLO network to detect individual words, then you'll get back the coordinates where each one of those words appear.  If you use the DarkHelp library or CLI, then [set the sort order to ESort::kPageOrder](https://www.ccoderun.ca/darkhelp/api/namespaceDarkHelp.html#a4e19a8fa7eb88e460dc99c6f9d143eb7) to have the results sorted top-to-bottom and left-to-right, otherwise you'll get them back in quasi-random order.  I demonstrate that in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BsLM4e3_oo) (skip to 4m50s) which is used to read letters instead of words.

If this is how you'd like to proceed, I suggest starting here with the YOLO FAQ:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#how_to_get_started

Comment: Thank you!
In your video you trained your model on letter detection and this is good idea, but I'm not sure how this will work for me. In this alphabet 36 letters + mention that this is HCR => I have to do something like a MNIST and I'm not quite sure about this idea...
I was thinking about making Transformer for the word recognition with CTC loss
But I at this moment I'm not sure how to realize it

Comment: Also I have an Idea to use seq2seq models, I think they have to work

Comment: Watch the first video, where I trained it on words and fields instead of letters.  It is easy to train a network, shouldn't be difficult to train it to detect the words in your document.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work :(

It hardly-badly predicts strings

Comment: You'd didn't annotate or train correctly.  I do this for a living.  Did you size the network correctly?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3Trxxt9RzE  If you need help, come join the YOLO discord where we can help you out:  https://discord.gg/zSq8rtW